# sql изменить стандартное значение колонки, значением из другой колонки

Tags: mysql, laravel

Как можно изменить стандартное значение имеющейся колонки значением из другой колонки?

Задача: имеются колонки `id` и `order`, требуется что бы изначально `id` и `order` были идентичны, далее возможно менять значение `order` для сортировки.

Comment: ID - небось автоинкремент?

Comment: да, id автоинкремент

Comment: Используйте триггер `AFTER INSERT`

Comment: можно пример если не трудно. Не сильно хорошо знаю синтаксис и боюсь надолго закопаться.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman Не получится. В триггере AFTER нельзя менять превдотаблицу NEW. В триггере нельзя выполнить UPDATE таблицы, на изменение которой срабатывает триггер.

Comment: @Ravil Рассмотрите такой вариант. Полю `order` не присваивается значение, оно получает значение NULL (либо NULL присваивается явно). Для сортировки по значению этого поля используется не `ORDER BY \`order\``, a `ORDER BY COALESCE(\`order\`, id)`. Если order не изменялось и там NULL - используется id, иначе изменённое не-NULL значение order.

Comment: @Akina бизнес задача подразумевает что в ордере будет уже id, так будет более удобная реализация со стороны интерфейса/клиента

Comment: @Akina, действительно, спасибо. Тогда можно предложить еще обновлять посредством второго запроса непосредственно из кода приложения.

Comment: @Ravil А если всё по-взрослому, то отойти от запросов и реализовывать логику (включая и логику вставки записи) через хранимую процедуру. А там несложно сделать и два запроса...

Comment: @Akina спасибо. буду все таки делать через приложение